# On clicking one link create a tab component and show some dynamic data in the tab

Tags: angular

I have a menu with some options(sub-menus)(not fixed). When I click on a submenu it should open in different tab with  set of data which I am getting from some api. Every submenu having different set of data.

I am not getting any proper idea to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

According to whatever I have understood from your question, briefly I will try to explain:

```
1.You will have to create different components for different views which will open on the click of each menu item
2.These components will have code which is displaying the data
3.You will also need a service to fetch the data which can be shared or separate according to your project's demand.
4.In the end you will need to use routing to navigate to these components. i.e each navigation item will have 'router-link' which is linked to the respective component.
```

Please read about Routing https://angular.io/guide/router and services as well. Hope this helps at all.

Comment: Let me put the points again
1- I have submenus which are dynamically created. e.g different type of reports
2- when user clicks on a submenu it should open in a new tab and  show the data which it will get from some api.

DOUBT:

I don't have components for them as all the links (submenus) are created dynamically and it is not fixed also.

Not getting any idea how to manage this.